# Angular2 ngFor skip first index

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

How can I skip the first index from the array?

```
<li *ngFor="#user of users">
    {{ user.name }} is {{ user.age }} years old.
  </li>
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You could use the  [slice pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html).

```
<li *ngFor="#user of users | slice:1">
  {{ user.name }} is {{ user.age }} years old.
</li>
```

The first parameter corresponds to a positive integer representing the start index.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the index value as it is? rather then moving to 0.

Comment: With the slice pipe, the index remains the same. Only the first element isn't taken into account in the iteration...

Comment: Actually index value went to 0, when I use slice..

Comment: Yes, since it's the value of the new array created by the pipe, a sub array

Comment: so how can I keep index value as same or starting from 1 rather then 0?

Comment: I would implement this like that: https://plnkr.co/edit/uFhCe0aEzbcmQXCHxmVX?p=preview

Comment: I end up doing the same thing :)

Comment: Cool ;-) In fact you can't evaluate expressions when initializing the index (something like `#i = index + 1`)...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405399/1569600 is the correct answer based on the `let user of users` syntax instead of the template variable. I tried updating this one but the edit didn't have enough characters :)

Answer (score 23):

There is the [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html) for this use case:

```
  <li *ngFor="let user of users | slice:1">
    {{ user.name }} is {{ user.age }} years old.
  </li>
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the index value as it is? rather then moving to 0.

Comment: What index value? You could try `<li *ngFor="#user of users | slice:1; #i=index-1">` if this is what you mean.

Comment: after using slice, my index values for first user went to 0 from 1. so I need to keep index value as it is.. starting from 1